# Log into FTP With proxy

Tags: proxy, network-programming

Is it possible to write Perl (or other language) code that logs into an FTP server with proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See here http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html

> Firewall - The name of a machine which
>   acts as an FTP firewall. This can be
>   overridden by an environment variable
>   FTP_FIREWALL . If specified, and the
>   given host cannot be directly
>   connected to, then the connection is
>   made to the firewall machine and the
>   string @hostname is appended to the
>   login identifier. This kind of setup
>   is also referred to as an ftp proxy.

But it's a question so obviously answerable by googling (it was the first match for "perl ftp proxy") that there must be more to the question. Tell us more about what you're trying to do.